# Twitter embedded tweets not showing up perfectly?

Tags: php, twitter

Here is the sample page to take a look at the issue [Tweets](http://8mags.com/bored/twitter/pasttweets01.php)

The tweets which have just text sometimes don't show up as expected(First tweets). Sometimes they show up normal(last tweet). Tweets with pictures work perfectly.

Here is the code that I add

```
<blockquote class="twitter-tweet" lang="en"><p><a href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/YoMama?src=hash">#YoMama</a> so stupid, she got locked in a meat locker and sweat to death! <a href="http://t.co/lo7sYI1d8I">http://t.co/lo7sYI1d8I</a></p>&mdash; YoMamaJokes (@YoMamaJokes247) <a href="https://twitter.com/YoMamaJokes247/status/533908344369844224">November 16, 2014</a></blockquote>
```

What could be the possible reason for this?

Comment: https://support.twitter.com/articles/20169559-embedding-a-tweet-on-your-website-or-blog

Comment: So, the tweets that don't show up are probably gone? I mean, deleted.

Comment: From the page you linked, the ones I tried were deleted. You can check them easily, just visit each link.

Comment: Yes,I did that. Thank you.